# how can i get the value of radiobox in jquery

Tags: jquery

how can i get the value of radiobox in jquery

```
<input type="radio" name="religion" class="chk" name="religion" value="muslim">Muslim
<input type="radio" name="religion" class="chk" name="religion" value="christian">Christian
<input type="radio" name="religion" class="chk" name="religion" value="hindu">Hindu
```

i have tried this, but i am not getting the value, how can i do this ?

```
var religion = $("name=religion").val();
alert(religion)
```

Comment: Just as a tip, searching "radio jquery" is a lot faster than writing out an entire question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get value of pressed checkbox by

```
var religion = $("input[name=religion]:checked").val();
alert(religion)
```

Comment: Thanks  !!! its working

Answer (score 0):

```js
const radio1Value = document.querySelector("input").value;
console.log(radio1Value);
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="religion" class="chk" name="religion" value="muslim">Muslim
<input type="radio" name="religion" class="chk" name="religion" value="christian">Christian
<input type="radio" name="religion" class="chk" name="religion" value="hindu">Hindu
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
            var radioValue = $("input[name='religion']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue){
                alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
            }
        });

    });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/santosh_singh/tcneuL4r/)

Answer (score -1):

You have `name="religion"` twice. You need to change one of them to `id="religion"`. then you can access the value with

```
var religion = $("#religion").val();
```